# Docker swarm - how to replicate a service on each node in the swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I would like to deploy a stack to a docker swarm where I want each node to run a given service.

I looked at `deploy.placement` configuration and the closest option I found is the placement preference `spread=node.label.abc` which will equally distribute the services on nodes matching the label. However this requires updating the replicas count all the time to match the number of nodes.

Is there a way to automatically deploy a service on all the nodes without manually updating the replica count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically deploy a service on all the nodes without manually updating the replica count?

Yes, deploy your service in [global mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#mode) instead of replicated. Example from the link:

```
version: '3'
services:
  worker:
    image: dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker
    deploy:
      mode: global
```

This will run a single instance of the container on every node matching your constraints.